# Using two If clauses in this sentence

Tags: conditional-constructions, clauses

I have received an invitation to visit a research lab for "several hours" in a well-known institution for potential hiring. I have provided them with my availability but I followed that with this sentence:

> If it possible and if you have a designated lab meeting day, I would be most interested in coming during that time.

>

**Q1**: Can I use two ifs in the same sentence as in the above one?

*Q2*: I know this is maybe not the place to ask this question, but does this sound like a reasonable request to ask during the hiring process?

I have found this ([Two if clauses in one sentence](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/212080/two-if-clauses-in-one-sentence)) but it does not answer my question because of the use of different clauses and conditions.

Comment: You may conjoin as many subordinate clauses as you wish. But "If it **is** possible...." But it clearly is possible because you already have an invitation. And don't you mean if they can receive you on the days that you're available? What happens if their "designated lab meeting day" doesn't match your schedule? And Q2: yes, a polite request to synchronize schedules is reasonable, especially if you have to make travel arrangements.

Comment: Thanks for your replay. Yes, you are right I have received an invitation but I am asking "if it is possible" that because there might be some reasons prevent them from allowing me to join their lab meeting i.e., they might discuss some confidential info. In my response, I have told them that I can arrange anytime if they let me know ahead of time. Does that make more sense to you now?

Comment: Let me be sure I understand. You've been invited to visit the institution, but you'd like to attend the lab meeting at that institution, and their invitation doesn't specifically include that meeting. Have I got that right?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right! Though the invitation stated clearly that I will spend "several hours" at the lab, which generally implies that I will be interacting with lab members so they can see if I am a good fit.